# Infinitest does not run @Before{Method,Class} methods when more than one TestNG group is used

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, testng, infinitest

I created a sample Eclipse project that demonstrates that [Infinitest](https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest) skips setup methods annotated with Before{Method,Class}, see https://github.com/jaeckel/InfinitestSampleProject. Because of this my tests fail when Infinitest executes them although they work when executed by Eclipse's TestNG plugin. The behaviour can be reproduced by [this test case](https://github.com/jaeckel/InfinitestSampleProject/blob/master/test/MultipleGroupsDontWorkTest.java).

Is this a bug? If yes, how can it be fixed? I had a quick look at the infinitest source but that did not reveal anything yet on how to fix it. I created [an issue for this](https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/99) and talked to the owner of the project. But so far, no one came back to me.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the Infinitest github repo has responded to your [issue](https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/99) and explained that this is not a bug in the product. He wrote:

> If a group is excluded, no test/setup/teardown annotated with this group will run.
>   If you want to run only 'automated' tests. Do include 'automated' group but don't exclude 'integration' group.

As you've indicated in the github issue, this advice has indeed resolved your issue. It might be a good idea to close this question :)